# XPath select all text content for a <div> inside that parent div exclude a specific <div> tag

Tags: html, xpath

Part of the HTML I'm querying:

```
<div class="author">   
    Tobi Raphael
    <div class="artdate"> Last Updated: 24 July 2014|16:25 GMT</div>
</div>
```

I need only "Tobi Raphael". I don't want `<div class"artdate"` elements.

I've tried below XPath expression but is not working:

```
[@class='author']/*/descendant-or-self::*[text() and not(self::div)]
```

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by root or the selected element.

Pretending we're in the root

```
/div[@class='author']/text()
```

this will out put all text inside your element including empty text as space , tabs , ect...:

```
Text='Tobi Raphael'
Text=''
```

If we want to avoid that

```
/div[@class='author']/text()[normalize-space(.) != '']
```

Output Just text :

```
Text='Tobi Raphael'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your query:

- It seems uncomplete, have you forgotten to copy something like `//div` in the beginning?
- Your query is doing something like "select all author `div`s, then all children, and all element nodes containing a text node, but not being a div". Select the text children instead. With XPath, you cannot *exclude* parts of a subtree, but need to specifically match which subtrees you want (here: the text node).

Select all direct text children of the author `div`:

```
//div[@class="author"]/text()
```

Depending on your XPath implementation, you might need to further filter for empty text nodes:

```
//div[@class="author"]/text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]
```

Comment: Had a typo in the queries, is fixed. For future: "it does not work" is _never_ a qualified problem report. Also applies to your question. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask], and [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).